# Is it correct to say 'small streets'?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

I think it is dangerous to ride a bicycle in Australia, because there is no cycle track in those small streets.

Is it correct to say 'small streets'? Is there any word that is better than 'small'?

(I googled, apparently 'small street' is the name of an App, which makes it hard to know whether it is correct to say it in a conversation.)

Thank you!

Comment: Consider "narrow streets" as a way to express the same thing.

Comment: For a humorous effect, you could try *puny road* or *teeny tiny road*. :)

Comment: I think a 'small' street just refers to the length and not 'width' e.g. I don't think anybody describe a street that's narrow but is 2 kilometers long a small street although _small streets_ are _short in width_, too.  BTW, speaking of length, is 'short street' a correct collocation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ISmall Streets

If you mean that the streets are of small or limited width, then you should say "narrow streets". In this sense, narrow is far more common and usual than small.

The use of small in this sentence is ambiguous. It doesn't necessarily mean that the streets are of limited width. I think it usually means that they are of limited length, or they are both limited in length and width.